# Encoding invariance for deep neural network

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, keras

I have a set of data, 2D matrix (like Grey pictures).
And use CNN for classifier.
Would like to know if there is any study/experience on the accuracy impact
if we change the encoding from traditionnal encoding.

I suppose yes, question is rather which transformation of the encoding make the accuracy invariant, which one deteriorates....

To clarify, this concerns mainly the quantization process of the raw data into input data.

EDIT:

Quantize the raw data into input data is already a pre-processing of the data, adding or removing some features (even minor). It seems not very clear the impact in term of accuracy on this quantization process on real dnn computation.
Maybe, some research available.

Comment: What do you mean by encoding, and what is the traditional encoding?

Comment: when you input date into a DNN, you need to encode the raw data into a tensor... Traditionnal one is 1toK or RGB color value...

Comment: If you mean 1 to K in terms of classification, or one hot encoding, those things don't impact accuracy. I am not sure what you mean by RGB color value, that is not an encoding.

Comment: RGB value is an encoding since value is between 0..255 for each layer of the tensor.  Encoding means also representation of the data, ie quantization of the raw date for input. It has an impact (quantization process).

Comment: RGB can be anything, it doesn't have to be [0, 255], you can input a RGB image in [0, 1] range, without any quantization. But how does RGB apply to your data?

Comment: This is not about RGB, this is about Quantization of the raw data (please have a look at Quantization in wikipedia or below answer...)

Comment: Good, that makes the question clearer :)

Comment: I think the question was clear, maybe you should have checked the meaning of quantization and input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any research specifically dealing with quantization of input data, but you may want to check out some related work on quantization of CNN parameters: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.06473v2.pdf.  Depending on what your end goal is, the "Q-CNN" approach may be useful for you.

My own experience with using various quantizations of the input data for CNNs has been that there's a heavy dependency between the degree of quantization and the model itself.  For example, I've played around with using various interpolation methods to reduce image sizes and reducing the color palette size, and in the end, I discovered that each variant required a different tuning of hyper-parameters to achieve optimal results.  Generally, I found that minor quantization of data had a negligible impact, but there was a knee in the curve where throwing away additional information dramatically impacted the achievable accuracy.  Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any way to determine what degree of quantization will be optimal without experimentation, and even deciding what's optimal involves a trade-off between efficiency and accuracy which doesn't necessarily have a one-size-fits-all answer.

On a theoretical note, keep in mind that CNNs need to be able to find useful, spatially-local features, so it's probably reasonable to assume that any encoding that disrupts the basic "structure" of the input would have a significantly detrimental effect on the accuracy achievable.

Answer (score 1):

In usual practice -- a discrete classification task in classic implementation -- it will have no effect.  However, the critical point is in the initial computations for back-propagation.  The classic definition depends only on strict equality of the predicted and "base truth" classes: a simple right/wrong evaluation.  Changing the class coding has no effect on whether or not a prediction is equal to the training class.

However, this function can be altered.  If you change the code to have something other than a right/wrong scoring, something that depends on the encoding choice, then encoding changes can most definitely have an effect.  For instance, if you're rating movies on a 1-5 scale, you likely want 1 vs 5 to contribute a higher loss than 4 vs 5.

Does this reasonably deal with your concerns?

---

I see now.  My answer above is useful ... but not for what you're asking.  I had my eye on the classification encoding; you're wondering about the input.

Please note that asking for off-site resources is a classic off-topic question category.  I am unaware of any such research -- for what little that is worth.

Obviously, there should be *some* effect, as you're altering the input data.  The effect would be dependent on the particular quantization transformation, as well as the individual application.

I do have some limited-scope observations from general big-data analytics.

In our typical environment, where the data were scattered with some inherent organization within their natural space (F dimensions, where F is the number of features), we often use two simple quantization steps: (1) Scale all feature values to a convenient integer range, such as 0-100; (2) Identify natural micro-clusters, and represent all clustered values (typically no more than 1% of the input) by the cluster's centroid.

This speeds up analytic processing somewhat.  Given the fine-grained clustering, it has little effect on the classification output.  In fact, it sometimes *improves* the accuracy minutely, as the clustering provides wider gaps among the data points.

Take with a grain of salt, as this is not the main thrust of our efforts.

Comment: It highlights the dependance on some specific user case (ie data and classifier results), thanks for this.  However, the topic seems larger, wondering if there is any published research done in that way (ex: image, words,...).